# Bitcoin Cash transaction history API

Tags: blockchain

I'm making an android Dapp which will work for Bitcoin Cash and other cryptocurrencies. In the app, I need to show all transaction history of a user. However, I can't find any 3rd party API to get all transaction history basing on addresses of a wallet. Anyone can help on this?

API should work on both TestNet and MainNet environment.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [btc.com](https://bch.btc.com/api-doc)'s API.

Their `address transactions API` seems to meet your needs.

> GET /address/{address}/tx

Examples

> https://bch-chain.api.btc.com/v3/address/15urYnyeJe3gwbGJ74wcX89Tz7ZtsFDVew/tx

Comment: It seems the API doesn't support TestNet.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a way to display a complete portfolio of a user's assets you should checkout Amberdata's API as they currently support, Ethereum & Ethereum tokens, Bitcoin, Bitcoin Cash, Bitcoin SV, Litecoin and Zcash.

You can check out their documentation [here](https://docs.amberdata.io).